# Unable to get the id of the panel in a datatable with paging and sorting

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a datatable which has expandable/collapsible bootstrap panels as rows.

This is how it looks like initially:

[image]

And this is after expanding one of the panels:

[image]

**Note:** The datatable has pagination and sorting.

The html of the panels(row):

```
<tr>
<td>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            @process
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-perform="panel-collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="pull-right">
                                                <em class="fa fa-plus"></em>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-wrapper collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;" id="pnl_@process" title="pnl_@process">
                                         //the table in the expanded panel here   

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

**Note:** The above html code is in a foreach loop which fills the data one row after the other(mvc view).

I have written a jquery code to get the id of the expanded panel:

```
$('.panel-wrapper').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            var pnlId = $(this).attr('id');       
            alert(pnlId.id + ' expanded');

            }
        });
```

However I get the correct ids only for the first page in the datatable. Since the second page, the  id comes as **undefined**. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Now I am able to get the id(thanks to GuruPrasad Rao) but I am also using that id to make the panel to expand on reload. Some thing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#' + pnlId).collapse("show");

});
```

However that is not working for the panels which are not in the first page. What change can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `$('.panel-wrapper')` for the later pages get constructed and appended to `DOM` once you navigate to `page` and hence it forms dynamic content and you need to use `event delegation` to manipulate dynamic contents as below:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse','.panel-wrapper', function () {
       var pnlId = $(this).attr('id');       
       alert(pnlId.id + ' expanded');
});
```

`$(document)` can be replaced with any static content like `table id` which will be there on `page load`

---

**UPDATE**

For your other issue you need to do it on every page change by using `bootstrap table`'s `onPageChange` method - **[docs](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/documentation.html)**

*For example*

```
$('#yourtableid').bootstrapTable({
}).on('page-change.bs.table', function (e, size, number) {
         //collapse the panel here
})
```

**[Doc Example](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#basic-events-table)**

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer...I am now getting the id using your code. However I am facing one more issue with it. I have updated so in the question. Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: HI..yes now I was able to get the panel to remain expanded. However I had to make some change; because the code was unable to recognize bootstrapTable. So I changed it to dataTable and then it started working. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)